# grep on Makefile

Tags: linux, bash, makefile

I have to do a grep to search a pattern in files in a folder. And then modify just this files with sed. And I have to do this on a Makefile.

But I have the problem that when I do:

```
a_files=$(grep -lr "pattern" /path/to/folder)
```

a_files is empty. I have the same result when a do:

```
a_files=$(grep -lr "pattern" | cut -f1 -d:)
```

I need this files on a array, because then I use it on a for cycle

**EDIT**:
I get more sample of my problem.

The problem occur when the code run on Makefile.

Makefile:

```
APP=/home/administrator/APP

test:
    for ii in $(grep -lr "<cmdExec>/opt/sao/app/ </cmdExec>" $(APP))
    do
        @echo $(ii)
    done
```

If I run `make test` I have this error:

```
for ii in
/bin/sh: 1: Syntax error: end of file unexpected
make: *** [test] Error 2
```

Thank for your help

Regards!

Comment: problem isn't with the code its working fine with me, `a_files=$(grep -lr "pattern" /path/to/folder)` produces desired results the issue is most likely with your pattern

Comment: Please ensure that you're providing sufficient code to let someone see the problem themselves just copy-and-pasting from the question with no changes. For example: `tempdir=$(mktemp -d tempdir.XXXXXX); mkdir -p "$tempdir/subdir"; echo pattern >"$tempdir/subdir/file"; grep -lr "pattern" "$tempdir"` would be code that might be expected to reproduce your problem (but doesn't). If you want to let anyone be confident in their answer, we need a [mcve] we can use without changes to see the issue ourselves in the first place.

Comment: Hello  @CharlesDuffy I let more information.

Comment: ahh -- this makes much more sense now; `make` and shell syntax interact in some odd ways (f/e, you need to use shell expansions, not make expansions, when a variable is set inside the same shell that's executing). I think the question is now answerable (that said, you could simplify it substantially: `for ii in  $(echo one two three); do` would have the same problem with no `grep` involved anywhere).

Comment: See `@for ii in $$(echo one two three); do echo "$$ii"; done` as an instructive example.